# Expo-RN: Google Sign In works locally but not on production

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to implement the **Sign in With Google** function on my Expo app. I installed the google-signin packaged advised by Expo (https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) and ran `npx expo run:android` to build the app.

I added the different keys from my Google API Console (Android and Web)

When I run locally on my Android simulator, the procedure goes fine and I am able to register:

- [screenshot on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ly2y.png)

When I run in production (in apk build), I do not get the above screenshot but a message telling me "Something went wrong"
[Error in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W8u4.png)
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDNMz.png)

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Note: I am not using Firebase for Google Authentication but I plan on using it for notifications so I already created the `google-services.json` file

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I have similar issue but mine not works at all on web or android emulator ?with this error on web `Uncaught Error: RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully.
If you are using Expo, make sure you are using Custom dev client, not Expo go` did you face such an error ? if not ? could you let me know your steps to achieve it ,it would be really a great help .  @CBongard